# Eclipse ignoring CucumberOptions in report generation

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, cucumber, noraui

I am facing an unexpected issue while trying to generate reports with Eclipse (Neon 3). I am using NoraUi V2.x.x which is a combination of Selenium,Cucumber,etc.

As you can see in [my attached screenshot below], I have added the following to my class:

```
@CucumberOptions(monochrome = true, glue = { "noraui.application.steps", 
"noraui.browser.steps", "com.soprasteria.cdk.ACEWS.application.steps.ACEWS"}, 
plugin = { "html:target/reports/html", "junit:target/reports/junit/cucumber.xml", "json:target/reports/json/cucumber.json" },
    features = { "src/test/resources" })
```

**However, at the end of my execution, Eclipse says:**

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (copy-gherkin-formatter-file) @ ACEWS ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
copy:[copy] Copying 1 file to D:\Profiles\rdesplats\workspace\ACEWS\target\reports\html
```

But there is no generation of the json file or xml file. 
Has anyone already faced this issue and knows how to resolve this ?

**My attached screenshot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Many thanks,

Rama

Comment: In your screenshot I see the Windows Explorer showing the `reports` directory with the subdirectory `html` and wonder what's in it (is it really empty)?

Comment: @howlger in this folder there is the html report but no json or xml file. According to the schema, the repository should have contained a junit folder and a json folder but none are present

Comment: I see. What does your `pom.xml` file look like?

Comment: @howlger you can find the file here : http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=41185378352362133505&t=4118537835236213350529295

Comment: _"However, at the end of my execution, Eclipse says: ..."_ <- caused by your `pom.xml`, line 228ff.

Comment: @howlger I saw it also when you asked me to send you the pom.xml. However I checked the src/test/ressources folder but there is no json file. In addition, it's just doing a copy as a PostIC which means they must have been created in the first place

Comment: What NoraUi version ? You need use NoraUi V3.x.x or more...

Answer (score 0):

You have to **enable Cucumber reporting** in your **`pom.xml`** file [as described here](https://damienfremont.com/2016/05/09/how-to-cucumber-test-report-plugin-2-with-maven-and-java/).

Comment: Thank you for all your answers but I tried thislink already. 

When i add the cucumber junit dependency, the build fails and it says "import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;" does not exist and then the "When", "Given" are not recongized in my feature

Comment: I don't think there's something wrong with your `<dependencies>`, but a `<plugin>` is missing.

Comment: I even added the plugin [as described here](https://github.com/damianszczepanik/maven-cucumber-reporting) but it didn't change anything

Comment: Did you add the `maven-cucumber-reporting` plugin and configured `<cucumberOutput>`? Did you get an error or has the `<cucumberOutput>` JSON not be generated?

Comment: I did and I have a warning "cucumber.json does not exist".

From the link you gave me, I have the feeling the cucumber-reporting is using the json file to display an enhanced report. 

I might be wrong but nevertheless I have no error on JSON file not being generated

Comment: Did you run it via Maven `clean test`?

Comment: @howlger's link doesn't seem to work, This one works: https://www.damienfremont.com/2016/05/09/how-to-cucumber-test-report-plugin-2-with-maven-and-java

Comment: Note that in that linked article `cucumberOutput` needs to be replaced with `<jsonFiles><param>**/cucumber.json</param></jsonFiles>`. Also, skippedFails and enableFlashCharts seem to be invalid now.